# Need to find all TextAreas that have an unsual character

Tags: soql, long-text-area

I have a long text area field which in some cases has characters that cause problems e.g. Vertical Tabs.  I need to find all instances where the field contains such a character I can't write a SOQL query to check this because you can't check for a long text area in a SOQL query.

So any tips how I could do this?

Thinking I might have to go via APEX.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Write a validation rule to prevent any/all special characters you want to locate and do a dummy data loader update to "touch" all records. The reject file should contain all the records with the special characters, thanks to the validation rule.